# SQL - Calculate two fields in one Case

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a sql query that calculates a field as follows:

```
  Select 
         Case When b.xField > 10
         then 20
         when b.xField > 48
         then 10
         else 0
         end as field1
 from (Select CASE WHEN numberChosen < 15
              THEN 10
              WHEN numberChosen > 15
              THEN 48 
              END as xField
        From secondTable) B
```

What I need is, when field1 is 10, then do some other calculations to save on another field.

Example something like:

```
       then 20 AND field2 = yData - 26
```

so when the case is on 20, then have another field equal to yData - 26.
Can that be achieved using Cases in Sql ? Have two fields calculated in a single case?

Comment: No. That requires another case expression on Field 2.

Comment: @dfundako but the calculation on field 2 depends on the field1.
Which is calculated with the cases,
when I start another Case WHEN `field1 = 20 ` i get field1 is unknown.
That's what I'm unsure how to manage.

Comment: _Columns_, not fields.

Comment: @AndrewS Do a cte for your first calc, then do another cte for your 2nd calc on field2, then return your final result set from cte2?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the base logic that is deciding when `field1 = 10` (ie. `xField > 48`) in the second case:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN xField > 48
            THEN 10
            WHEN xField > 10
            THEN 20
            ELSE 0
       END as field1,
       CASE WHEN xField > 48
            THEN yData - 26
       END as field2
FROM (SELECT CASE WHEN numberChosen < 15
                  THEN 10
                  WHEN numberChosen > 15
                  THEN 48 
             END as xField,
             yData
      FROM secondTable) B
```

I changed the order of your case because putting the `> 10` condition before the `> 48` condition will never let the `> 48` be hit.

Comment: Thank you. But the doubt that I'm having is that xField itself is already a result of another calculation. And that I've done in a subquery.
So something like:
`Select Case when... as field1 FROM (Select Case ... as xField) `, so xField helps calculate field1.
And I need field1 to calculate field2

Comment: @AndrewS Try the first approach.  Just copy paste your current query into the `(yourCurrentQuery)` placeholder.  You may need to add column aliases if you don't have them.  Simplified, it will look like this: `SELECT field1, CASE..END field2 FROM (SELECT CASE..END field1 FROM table) q`

Comment: Thank you,I understand that, but I'm saying that's how the query looks because xField is calculated in that subquery and then in the cases the field1 uses it.
Now I needed to use field 1 for different query.
What's confusing and I dont' know how efficient would be to add another subquery for field2 that I need. It would make 3

Comment: @AndrewS Add your current query to your question so I can adjust my answer based on what you have now.  You can simplify it if it's way more complex than necessary, but be sure to include the case/nesting logic you are describing.

Comment: @Asron Dietz, I did add it. Of course I'm simplifying it using numbers,But basically it's this. Use a calculated column to calculate another column, but the first column is also calculated..

Comment: @AndrewS I updated my answer.  Not sure where `ydata` is coming from but the concept is there.  Instead of using `CASE WHEN field1 = 10` when building out `field2`, use `CASE WHEN xField > 48`.  Since `field1` is set to 10 only when `xField > 48`, this accomplishes the same thing as directly referencing `field1` would.  Hopefully that is clear.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to calculate two fields in one Case

You Can't Do That™.

You can put two case clauses in your query like this:

```
 Select 
     Case When xField > 10
     then 20
     when xField > 48
     then 10
     else 0
     end as field1,
    Case When xField > 10
     then ydata - 26
     else 0
     end as field2

from myData
```

Or you can generate the extra field value in a wrapper query if it is really hard to compute field2

```
SELECT field1, CASE WHEN field1 > 10 THEN ydata -20 ELSE 0 END field2
  FROM (
    Select 
     ydata, 
     Case When xField > 10
     then 20
     when xField > 48
     then 10
     else 0
     end as field1
  from myData
) subquery
```